# SharePoint 2013 Hide Document Library List from view from users without view permissions

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a site with multiple Document Libraries, I only want users to see those Libraries that they have permissions to 'READ' in their left hand panel view. Can this be done, if so, how please?

Comment: Could you explain what "left hand panel view" is?

Comment: you have a view on the left side of the page of the Available Document Libraries to the end user - Is there a way, based on permissions, set it so that if the end user does not have access to a particular Library, that person can not see it in that List.